# Django CSRF verification failed even with {% csrf_token %}

Tags: python, django, csrf-protection, django-csrf

POST requests to the Django view below result in (403) CSRF verification failed. I've confirmed that the hidden csrf token gets rendered in the page's source. I am also able to make POST requests without errors in other views. I'm unsure how to debug further.

**views.py:**

```
def email(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        fd = open('emaildb.csv','a')
        fd.write(email+',somefile\n')
        fd.close()
        return render(request, 'receipts/email.html', {'text':'Thanks, we''ll get back to you soon.'})
    else:
        return render(request, 'receipts/email.html',)
```

**email.html:**

```
<form action="email" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    {% csrf_token %}
    E-mail:<br>
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Comment: How about removing the `enctype="text/plain"` and try again? Also try not to use `action="email"` and instead use `action="{% url 'name_of_url' %}"` or if you're POSTing in the same view you can omit the `action="email"` altogether.

Comment: It doesn't mean you have a valid token, even though you see it in the page source. It could be expired one too.

Comment: nik_m is correct, simply removing the enctype="text/plain" solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

U can't call method like that

```
<form action="email" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    {% csrf_token %}
    E-mail:<br>
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

in your urls.py u must write

```
url(r'^email/$', views.email, name='email')
```

and call this method using form like that

```
<form action="{% url 'your_folder_name_where_located_your_urls.py:email'%}" method="post" enctype="text/plain">
    {% csrf_token %}
    E-mail:<br>
    <input type="text" name="email">
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```